# Recessed Can Light Not Working

Tags: recessed-lighting

I have 2 recessed can lights that are controlled from the same wall switch.  I replaced both with LED bulbs.  After several months, in one of the lights the bulb would go off and on intermittently.  I replaced the bulb with the same result.  After about 3 weeks of this pattern the bulb will not work at all.  The other fixture on the line has had no issues.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the the center contact has loosened up in the fixture, with the power off pry the contact up a little and that may solve the problem. There are usually temp sensors in can lights but since changing the bulb made it work for a while I would check the center contact on the fixture. LED's usually will not produce enough heat to trip the thermal sensor. It could be a loose connection in the wiring, but again, since changing the bulb made it work, check the center contact.